# How to extract IP address from log file and append it to an URL?

Tags: bash, curl, grep

Log file contains this line.

```
Nov 28 21:39:25 soft-server sshd[11946]: Accepted password for myusername from 10.0.2.2 port 13494 ssh2
```

I want to run the curl command only if the log file contains the string "Accepted password for" and append the IP address to URL.

Something like this:

```
if [ grep -q "Accepted password for" var/log/auth.log]
then
    curl 'www.examplestextmessage.com/send-a-message/text=$IP_address'
fi
```

Additionally, how to rewrite the above script which can check multiple logins and to run separate `curl` commands for each results?

for eg:

Nov 28 21:35:25 localhost sshd[565]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22

Nov 28 21:39:25 soft-server sshd[11946]: Accepted password for myusername 
from 10.0.2.2 port 13494 ssh2

Nov 28 21:40:25 localhost sshd[565]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22

Nov 28 21:41:25 localhost sshd[565]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22

Nov 28 21:42:25 localhost sshd[565]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22

Nov 28 21:43:25 soft-server sshd[11946]: Accepted password for myusername from 10.0.1.1 port 13494 ssh2

Comment: *script which can check multiple logins* - show the respective input

Comment: it's good to have the formatted input in the question, not within a comments

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm new to this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -oP 'Accepted password for \w+ from\s\K[^ ]+' log.file|while read line;
     do 
     curl "www.examplestextmessage.com/send-a-message/text=$line"
 done
```

Explanation:
First `grep` will list the IP addresses from the line containing the words "Accepted password for". Then the stream of `grep` result is feeded into `while loop` to append ip addresses to `curl` and execute curl.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

1 line script with xargs:

```
grep -oP 'Accepted password for \w+ from\s\K[^ ]+' "/var/log/auth.log" | xargs -I{} -r curl -v -L "www.examplestextmessage.com/send-a-message/text={}"
```

`xarg -r` If the standard input is completely empty, do not run the command. By default, the command is run once even if there is no input.

`xarg -I{}` option changes the way the new command lines are built. Instead of adding as many arguments as possible at a time, xargs will take one name at a time from its input, look for the given token ({} here) and replace that with the name.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation :

1. grep the content "Accepted password for"
2. From result set find ip address using awk/cut
3. use IP address list as input for loop

below is code example

```
for IP_address in  `cat auth.log | grep 'Accepted password for' | awk '{print $11}'`
do
curl "www.examplestextmessage.com/send-a-message/text=$IP_address"
done
```

Comment: `\`cat auth.log | grep 'Accepted password for' | awk '{print $11}'`\` is deprecated style. Now better use `$( cat auth.log | grep 'Accepted password for' | awk '{print $11}')`

Answer (score 0):

Another option for completeness is sed using -E to cater for regular expressions:

```
sed  -En 's/(^.*Accepted password for )(.*)( from )(.*)( port.*$)/\4/p'
```

This will split the text into five separate sections signified by extracts in between brackets. We then focus on the 4th extract to get the ip address